# Mocking only middle layer of nested blocks with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I'm writing some code using this gem called [`kubernetes_leader_election`](https://github.com/grosser/kubernetes_leader_election#usage) which helpfully has a full example showing how to use it in its README. My usage of it is basically the same as what the README says, but here are the most relevant lines:

```
lease_name = self.class.name.underscore.gsub(/[\/_]+/, "=")
is_leader = false
elector = KubernetesLeaderElection.new(lease_name, kubeclient, logger: Rails.logger)
Thread.new { elector.become_leader_for_life { is_leader = true } }
sleep 1 until is_leader
```

I'm trying to write a spec that tests that the `lease_name` I passed in is what I expect, and that the code will not sleep forever if the block, `{ is_leader = true }`, executes. I know how to mock `KubernetesLeaderElection.new`, but I'm kind of new to using rspec mocks, so I'm really struggling to mock `elector.become_leader_for_life` with the same robustness (being able to test what it gets passed.) I've tried a bunch of variations on this overall concept, but none do quite what I need, and most give errors. Here's my latest attempt, which doesn't fail, but doesn't test everything I want:

```
describe LeaderElectionMixin
  class MixinUser
    include LeaderElectionMixin
  end

  describe "#wait_to_be_leader" do
    let(:dummy_client) { double(Kubeclient::Client) }
    let(:dummy_elector) { double(KubernetesLeaderElection) }

    before do
      allow(Kubeclient::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(dummy_client)
      expect(dummy_elector).to receive(:become_leader_for_life) do |&block|
        # only checks that the actual block and this proc return the same thing
        expect(block).to match(Proc.new { true })
      end.and_yield
    end

    it "should create leases based on the class name" do
      expect(KubernetesLeaderElection).to receive(:new)
        .with("mixin-user", dummy_client, logger: Rails.logger)
        .and_return(dummy_elector)
      MixinUser.new.wait_to_be_leader
    end
  end
end
```

(EDIT with update: If I use `.and_yield`, I can get past the problem of rspec hanging, but it's not a full solution yet, because I can't test an actual match of the block contents because `.and_yield` makes my block not be the end of the chain, more info [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1182#issuecomment-332087650). If I move `.and_yield` before the block, then `expect(block)` is `expect(nil)`. No idea why.)

The problems I've had with my approaches have been either that rspec hangs because `is_leader = true` is not executed, so `sleep 1 until is_leader` will run forever, or (with my latest implementation) I can get the original block to execute, but I can't make assertions that it did, I can only infer that it did because the spec ends. I have tried various suggestions from StackOverflow and GitHub threads that say I should be able to say `expect(block).to be` either the string that is the exact contents of the block code, or a Proc that contains the same code, but approaches don't work because the actual value is a Proc (so the suggestions to use strings don't work) and it's not the same Proc object (so `be` and `eq` don't work.) I have also tried attaching `.and_wrap_original` to various places, but that either gives me an error or gives me the same behavior as this example. The best I can do is `match` to at least check that the return value of the block is the same as the Proc I make. I am utterly lost. I know I can just switch to using an instance variable, but I don't want to expose that to classes including my mixin.

So to summarize, I:

1. Definitely need the most inner block, `is_leader = true`, to actually execute, and would *like* to test that its contents are what I specify;
2. Definitely need the middle block, `elector.become_leader_for_life`, to not call the original code (because it's a third party library and I don't want to mock details of its implementation;)
3. Don't really care whether the outer layer, `Thread.new`, actually executes (the spec doesn't need the code to be multithreaded, that's only there for runtime efficiency, hence why I mocked out `sleep` for my specs.)

How can I achieve this "mocking only the middle block" behavior without resorting to tainting the code with mocking smells like using instance variables?

Comment: I admit I didn't read your question very carefully, but seems like you never join the thread so it never executes?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel `Thread.new` lets the thread start executing. I technically don't need to `join`. Actually, I think due to a quirk of this library, I'm not supposed to. Regardless, this code works in practice, but it's hard to mock for rspec. This is not a question about threading, thankfully!

Comment: Yeah FYI @MikeSzyndel, `sleep` yields to other threads.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help here, I've never even seen that code you have for verifying the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with what this does:

```
expect(block).to be("is_leader = true")
```

but the code:

```
expect(dummy_elector).to receive(:become_leader_for_life) do |&block|
  expect(block).to be("is_leader = true")
end
```

doesn't ever execute the block it's receiving, so `is_leader` will never be changed.

Assuming you can get the source of a block, could you do something like:

```
expect(dummy_elector).to receive(:become_leader_for_life) do |&block|
  block.call
end
```

potentially with the `block.call` conditional on the block source?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I recently figured out something similar to what you're suggesting, and I updated my question accordingly. It's still not quite all the way to doing what I want, since I can't test the contents of the block. Please let me know what you think of my revised question.

Comment: Could you try using my approach to call the block instead of `and_yield` so that the block isn't wrapped?

Comment: I did, and while it works just as well as `and_yield`, it didn't let me do anything like expect the block to be be such-and-such like I had seen in guides and threads online. It's useful to know that doing `.call` is an equivalent approach, though!

Comment: Adding a check for the contents of `block.source`, along with your suggestion here, worked out for me. Thanks!